# If statement can't find the test variable in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following bash script (test_script.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
case=test

var1=90
echo "var1 = $var1"

var2=$(( var1 * 4 ))
echo "var2 = $var2"

if (( var1 > 80 ))
then
        pot=filled
else
        pot=empty
fi

    cat > message.txt << EOF
   Hellow world! The pot is $pot .
EOF
```

The output of this script is:

```
var1 = 90
var2 = 360
./test_script.sh: 10: ./test_script.sh: var1: not found
```

What is the cause for this "var1: not found" message ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your if statement is missing the "$": `if (( $var1 > 80 ))`

Comment: eblock, That didn't work. when I do that the message is: "90: not found"

Comment: See the question marked as duplicate, it's the same issue. You are running your script with `sh`, not `bash`. In `sh` scripts, `(( ... ))` is just a nested subshell, not an arithmetic evaluation at all.

Comment: @eblock If this was running with `bash` (not `sh`), the `(( ... ))` introduces an arithmetic context. There is no need to use `$` on variables in arithmetic contexts in `bash`.